# Playa php errors after upgrade to 4.4.1

Tags: playa

I upgraded to the latest version of playa (unsucessfully with Upgrader then manuallly). The module and field type are showing as 4.4.1 ok but I am getting php errors on all pages that contain playa fileds:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'rel.parent_is_draft' in 'where clause'

SELECT DISTINCT(rel.child_entry_id) AS entry_id FROM exp_playa_relationships     
rel WHERE rel.parent_entry_id = 5416 AND rel.parent_is_draft = 0 AND
rel.parent_field_id = 188 ORDER BY rel.rel_order
```

Comment: I'm also having this problem. I'm not using Upgrader.

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the upgrade instructions and go to the license key setting page? (http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/updating)

Comment: This should be the fix. 

As Andris indicates, go to the CP>Add-Ons>Fieldtypes>Playa, and click Submit.

This is the part of the Update that causes the field to be added, and you should be ok from there.

Comment: that is, 'causes parent_is_draft to be added' -- couldn't edit comment.

Comment: No. I'm afraid going to the CP>Add-Ons>Fieldtypes>Playa, and clicking Submit did not sort the issue! I tried this before posting the question.

Comment: Shoot us an email to support@pixelandtonic.com with CP details and referencing this question in that case - let's have a looksies!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrader may have failed, but it most likely modified a few things in the database making the manual update not right.

I'd try a few things.

1) Re-import database backup from prior to the failed Upgrader attempt.

if you don't have the backup...
2) Backup now, and uninstall Playa module (not extension), then reinstall the module.

if that didn't work...
3) Contact Playa official support at http://pixelandtonic.com/support

Comment: I'm afraid that has not worked

Comment: I have reinstalled an earlier version of Playa and it is working ok so the issue doesn't seem to be a DB one.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks for letting us know.